# How to refactor the code so one method for the two web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, webforms, refactoring

If i have two web forms like this :

```
public partial class frm_createVac : System.Web.UI.Page

public partial class frm_editVac : System.Web.UI.Page
```

and both of pages have the following same method :

---

```
 private void FillVacations()
        {
            DataTable dt = DAL.Vacation.GetVacationTypes();
            ddl_vac_type.Items.Clear();
            ddl_vac_type.DataSource = dt;
            ddl_vac_type.DataTextField = "vac_name";
            ddl_vac_type.DataValueField = "vac_code";
            ddl_vac_type.DataBind();

            ListItem item = new ListItem("-SELECT-", "-1");
            ddl_vac_type.Items.Insert(0, item);
        }
```

How to refactor my code so that i have one method for both pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a super class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page and then have your classes inherit from that super class. Then you define the method within your super class and use it in your child class:

```
public partial class Vacationpage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
        //define atttributes
        public Vacationpage()
        {
        }

        private void FillVacations()
        { 
        DataTable dt = DAL.Vacation.GetVacationTypes();
        ddl_vac_type.Items.Clear();
        ddl_vac_type.DataSource = dt;
        ddl_vac_type.DataTextField = "vac_name";
        ddl_vac_type.DataValueField = "vac_code";
        ddl_vac_type.DataBind();

        ListItem item = new ListItem("-SELECT-", "-1");
        ddl_vac_type.Items.Insert(0, item);
        }        
}
```

Then you do this:

```
public partial class frm_createVac : Vacationpage

public partial class frm_editVac : Vacationpage
```

In these classes you can use FillVacations().
And then you have your code defined in one place.

Answer (score 0):

edited yesterday @StarterPack mistype in answer, I've take a look again on your question and realized that better choice in your case is helper method, not to depend on markup or control Ids. Assuming you are using DropDownList it will be

```
public class VacationHelper
{
    public static void FillVacations(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList ddl)
    {
        DataTable dt = DAL.Vacation.GetVacationTypes();
        ddl.Items.Clear();
        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        ddl.DataTextField = "vac_name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "vac_code";
        ddl.DataBind();

        ListItem item = new ListItem("-SELECT-", "-1");
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, item);
    }
}
```

and call it on each page

```
VacationHelper.FillVacations(ddl_vac_type);
```